# Python3 reading a binary file, 4 bytes at a time and xor it with a 4 byte long key

Tags: python, byte

I want to read a binary file, get the content four bytes by four bytes and perform int operations on these packets.

Using a dummy binary file, opened this way:

```
with open('MEM_10001000_0000B000.mem', 'br') as f:
    for byte in f.read():
            print (hex(byte))
```

I want to perform an encryption with a 4 byte long key, `0x9485A347` for example.

Is there a simple way I can read my files 4 bytes at a time and get them as int or do I need to put them in a temporary result using a counter?

My original idea is the following:

```
        current_tmp = []
        for byte in data:
            current_tmp.append(int(byte))
            if (len(current_tmp) == 4):
                    print (current_tmp)
                    # but current_tmp is an array not a single int
                    current_tmp = []
```

In my example, instead of having `[132, 4, 240, 215]` I would rather have `0x8404f0d7`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use the "amount" parameter of read to read 4 bytes at a time, and the "from_bytes" constructor of Python's 3 `int` to get it going:

```
with open('MEM_10001000_0000B000.mem', 'br') as f:
    data = f.read(4)
    while data:
        number = int.from_bytes(data, "big")
        ...
        data = f.read(4)
```

If you are not using Python 3 yet for some reason, `int` won't feature a `from_bytes` method - then you could resort to use the struct module:

```
import struct
...
    number = struct.unpack(">i", data)[0]
    ...
```

These methods however are good for a couple interations, and could get slow for a large file - Python offers a way for you to simply fill an array of 4-byte integer numbers directly in memory from an openfile - which is more likely what you should be using:

```
import array, os
numbers = array.array("i")
with open('MEM_10001000_0000B000.mem', 'br') as f:
    numbers.fromfile(f, os.stat('MEM_10001000_0000B000.mem').st_size // numbers.itemsize)
numbers.byteswap()
```

Once you have the array, you can xor it with something like

```
from functools import reduce #not needed in Python2.7
result = reduce(lambda result, input: result ^ input, numbers, key)
```

will give you a `numbers` sequence with all numbers in your file read-in as 4 byte, big endian, signed ints.

If you file is not a multiple of 4 bytes, the first two methods might need some adjustment - fixing the `while` condition will be enough.

Comment: The OP wants `[132, 4, 240, 215]` to convert to `0x8404f0d7`, i.e, you need big-endian.

Comment: Thanks - fixed both things